# How can I see what my phone's wireless Mbps max transfer rate is?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, data-transfer, mobile-phone

From what I understand a wireless network connection is only as fast as the slowest device's max speed. So if my phone is talking to my router on a 5GHz band that is capable of 1300 Mbps transfer speed but can only send data at a speed of 500Mbps that is as quickly as data will be sent/received.

So, I have a Kyocera Brigadier phone. I want to know what its max Mbps transfer speed is. I've looked at the specs but could not find what I need to know.

Where can I find this information?

Comment: Does the phone not have a wireless NIC that has specs?

Comment: based on [phone specification](https://www.kyoceramobile.com/brigadier/Brigadier-Consumer-Spec-Sheet.pdf): Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac ([more about WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocol))

Comment: It's ac, but does that mean my phone can transfer at 1300 Mbps? @Ricardo

Comment: Mobiles are off-topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill why? Where should/could I ask this? Thanks

Comment: @CodeFlava Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
It's an Android phone so ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum Wi-Fi signaling rate (PHY rate) between a client and an AP is not quite as simple as "whatever the slowest one supports". Instead it's determined by the *intersection* of the different "Modulation and Coding Schemes" (MCS), spatial streams, channel widths, guard intervals both the client an the AP support. So if the particular capabilities of the client and AP don't overlap very well, the max PHY rate of the client-AP pair might be significantly less than the max PHY rate that the same client or AP could achieve when paired with a devices whose capabilities overlaps better.

Example:

I've seen a case where the AP supported a 150Mbps flavor of 802.11n, the client supported a 300Mbps flavor of 802.11n, but the intersection of their capabilities only yielded a 72.2Mbps flavor of 802.11n:

AP (N150):

- MCS 7
- 1 spatial stream
- 40MHz channels in 2.4GHz
- short guard interval
  (note: AP was 2.4GHz-only)

Client (N300):

- MCS15
- 2 spatial streams
- 40MHz channels *only in 5GHz*; only 20MHz channels in 2.4GHz
- short guard interval
  (client was dual-band)

…but since the client could only do 20MHz channels in 2.4GHz, and the AP could only do 2.4GHz, the intersection of the client's capabilities and the AP's capabilities ended up with just a 72.2Mbps PHY rate:

- MCS7 (AP's limitation)
- 1 spatial stream (AP's limitation)
- 20MHz channel (client's limitation in 2.4GHz, and AP only supported 2.4GHz)
- short guard interval (both AP and client supported this)

So even though they each supported flavors of 802.11n that were much faster than 802.11g, the way that they didn't have good overlap in their capabilities meant that could only get a max PHY rate of 72.2Mbps, which isn't much faster than 802.11g's top PHY rate of 54Mbps. Bummer.

The public documentation someone linked to for that Kyocera Brigadier only mentions that it support 802.11ac, but it doesn't mention how many spatial streams it supports, or what MCSes it supports, or what channel widths it supports, etc.

I've definitely seen 802.11ac products that only support a single spatial stream, and I've seen ones that don't support QAM256 (MCS 8 and 9), but I think every device I've seen supports 80MHz-wide channels and short guard interval. It's unlikely that a phone supports 3 spatial streams (not enough room for 3 antennas, not enough battery capacity for 3 radio chains), and devices that don't support MCS 8 or 9 are pretty rare from what I've seen, so your device is most likely capable of VHT80 MCS 9x1 (433.3Mbps) or VHT80 MCS 9x2 (866.6Mbps).

If you can use an 802.11 monitor mode packet sniffer to capture the phone's 802.11 Association Request packet when it joins your AP, you could see what your phone's radio claims it's capable of.

Some APs will tell you, in the management UI, what radio capabilities the currently-connected clients are capable of. So look to see if your AP tells you that.

Maybe there is software you can run on your Android phone to let you see the hardware capabilities of your radio.

Maybe you can look if there's a Wi-Fi radio built into the mobile phone chipset your Brigadier, and if so, what are the Wi-Fi capabilities of that built-in radio.

**Edited to Add:** Okay, your Brigadier uses a [Qualcomm Snapdragon 400](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/processors/400), and according to Qualcomm's specs, that chipset supports 802.11ac, 1 spatial stream, 256-QAM, and 80MHz-wide channels, so it has a max PHY rate of probably 433.3Mbps but possibly as little as 351Mbps (depending on MCS 8x1 vs 9x1, and short guard interval vs long guard interval). HOWEVER, Qualcomm says its throughput actually peaks out at 150Mbps, which suggests that it has other chip-architecture limitations that keep it from being able to fully utilize the medium at those max PHY rates.

**Edited again to add:** Once you know the major performance-critical specs of your device's Wi-Fi chipset (supported MCSes, max channel width, number of spatial streams, and shortest supported guard interval), you look it up in the tables in the IEEE 802.11 standard or use a cheat sheet like https://mcsindex.com/ to see what maximum signaling rate (PHY rate) your device can support under ideal radio conditions, when talking to an AP capable of all the same speed-critical features. Then to translate that raw rate into a reasonable expectation for application throughput, subtract typical Wi-Fi overhead of about 30%. But as we saw in the case of your Kyocera Brigadier's Qualcomm Snapdragon 400, sometimes a chipset has implementation-specific internal bottlenecks which limit the performance to something below what an 802.11 radio of those specs should be capable of, so in that case you may have to get ahold of the detailed chipset specs that chipset vendors sometimes only make available to hardware manufacturers that are looking to buy those chips.

Comment: Coming back to this years later and finding it very helpful! -- Even though it is off topic :/

Comment: @IEnjoyEatingVegetables Off topic? Oh I think I see what you mean. I've edited it just now to cover specifically the "Where can I look this up?" part of the question. The short answer is once you know the optional speedups your device is capable of, to find the actual max PHY rate that implies, you look it up in the tables in the IEEE 802.11 standard, or on a cheat sheet like mcsindex.com.

Comment: No! Don't edit it, haha. It is great. If you look in the comments of my question moderator DavidPostill says the question is off topic!